# when we use Semaphore in consumer and producer buffer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am working on BoundedBuffer class in consumer and producer we want to use the Semaphore in that class
we did that but there are an error in every use of **acquire()**
the rerror is:

**unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown**

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class BoundedBuffer implements Buffer { 
    private static final int   BUFFER_SIZE = 4;

    /**
     * volatile does not appear in the printed text. A discussion of
     * volatile is in chapter 7.
     */
    private volatile int count;
    private Object[] buffer;
    private int in;   // points to the next free position in the buffer
    private int out;  // points to the next full position in the buffer

    private Semaphore  mutex;
    private Semaphore  empty;
    private Semaphore full;

    public BoundedBuffer() { //constractur
        // buffer is initially empty
        //count = 0;
        in = 0;
        out = 0;

        buffer = new Object[BUFFER_SIZE];

        mutex = new Semaphore(1);
        empty = new Semaphore(BUFFER_SIZE);
        full = new Semaphore(0);
    }

    // producer calls this method
    public void insert(Object item) {
        //while (count == BUFFER_SIZE) 
        // ; // do nothing the brach full

        // add an item to the buffer
        // ++count;

        empty.acquire();
        mutex.acquire();
        buffer[in] = item;
        in = (in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;//that to do cyrcle or to go to the begining againe
/*
        if (count == BUFFER_SIZE)
            System.out.println("Baker put " + item + " Shelf FULL");
        else
            System.out.println("Baker put " + item + " Shelf Size = " +  count);
*/


        mutex.release();
        full.release();

    }

    // consumer calls this method
    public Object remove() {
        //Object item;
        full.acquire();
        mutex.acquire();

        //while (count == 0) 
            ; // do nothing the buffer is empty

        // remove an item from the buffer
        //--count;

        Object item = buffer[out];
        out = (out + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
        mutex.release();
        empty.release();
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I do not understand your application completely, but could not you just use the bounded buffer class that is already provided in the java.util.concurrent package ([ArrayBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html))?

> This is a classic "bounded buffer", in
>   which a fixed-sized array holds
>   elements inserted by producers and
>   extracted by consumers. Once created,
>   the capacity cannot be increased.
>   Attempts to put an element to a full
>   queue will result in the put operation
>   blocking; attempts to retrieve an
>   element from an empty queue will
>   similarly block.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you all you need to know; InterruptedException may be thropwn by acquire - hence you need to either a) catch it and handle it or b) allow it to propagate out of the calling function - necessitating you adding it to the functions throws sepcification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle exceptions thrown by the [acquire](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire()) method.

- [Java Tutorial: Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)
- Brian Goetz: [Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236.html)